# Detail sections not printing if previous section fills entire page

Tags: crystal-reports

My report has three detail sections. The first 2 contain sub reports. If either of the first two sections expands to be exactly large enough to fill the page, the following detail sections don't print at all.

I would expect a page break to be triggered and the following sections be printed on the next page, but this doesn't happen if it's nearly the size of the whole page, or greater. How can I fix this?

Comment: please share your code what you have tried so far??

Comment: normally it should go to second page... can you show preview?

Comment: I took over this project that was created by someone else. The report is contained in an rpt file. When I get time I'll try to figure out how to send something that works with data to show the problem. Thank you for responding. It may take me a little while to get time to make something I can send.